# Microsoft Edge IE Mode compatible with Java Runtime Applet?

Tags: browser, java, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, java-applet

I'm really having a hard time getting a straight answer from Microsoft on whether this is possible.

Situation:

My organization has an internally-hosted Oracle application which currently runs on Internet Explorer and uses JRE 8u144.

As Microsoft has stated that support for IE is ending on June 15th, we're scrambling to find a solution to keep this application working.

The options we're currently exploring:

1. Microsoft Edge IE Mode
2. A 2017 version of Firefox that allows Plug-ins.

Obviously, the 2nd option is not preferable as this would be highly insecure. Regardless, At the moment this seems to be the option we're having the most success with. We are researching ways of restricting web browsing on Firefox to ONLY this webpage and blocking all other internet traffic.

For IE Mode, I was able to make some progress but am getting stuck.

On their official ["Getting Started Guide"](https://query.prod.cms.rt.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWEHMs) it states:

"IE mode supports the following Internet Explorer functionality: All document modes and enterprise modes, ActiveX controls
(such as Java or Silverlight), Browser Helper Objects, et al."

This tells me that it should work, but I'm not having a lot of success.

I've so far:

1. created an Enterprise Site List and added the URL I'm testing.
2. created an Azure Security Group with only me as a member.
3. Created a MEM Configuration Profile to apply the site list to my user account.

When I open the webpage, it does have the IE Mode icon appear in the Address bar, so at least that is working.

The primary issue I'm having is that my login credentials aren't being properly passed to the webpage.

I can successfully log in without any issue into the website using IE11, but the very same credentials show "Login Failed" when using Microsoft Edge. I am suspecting this may have to do with a Java interaction that is not functioning properly.

I did submit a support request on 365 Admin Center but they're telling me I have to go to MS Edge Enterprise support, which has some extra subscription we need to pay for.

I first tried submitting a request on [Microsoft Edge Insider Portal](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/support/request) but this appears to be Consumer-level support.

When this request was closed, they told me to submit a request on [MS Edge Enterprise Support](https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/create). This evidently requires a separate subscription from our M365 and Azure AD Premium P1 account.

tl;dr, Any suggestions? We'd much prefer using IE Mode in Edge, vs. using an old version of Firefox, but we're kind of at a roadblock here.

Comment: [If this Java applet requires NPAPI support then what you want is NOT possible with Microsoft Edge.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816839/how-do-i-enable-java-in-microsoft-edge-web-browser#:~:text=You%20cannot%20open%20Java%20Applets%20%28nor%20any%20other,a%20couple%20of%20things%20that%20you%20can%20do%3A)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually read that thread before posting here. While I agree that Edge on it's own does not support NPAPI plugins and BOHs, it's unclear if "IE Mode" within Edge using an Enterprise Site List would bypass this.

Documentation by Microsoft claims that they support Java and ActiveX Plugins on IE Mode.

Comment: Edge has zero support for NPAPI because Chromium has zero support.